# Resonant response of oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

Within my lectures on SHM we covered the basics of resonance. To get an equation for displacement one step was used which I am not comfortable with.

My lecturer said that there is a perfect balance between spring force and acceleration (the examples used were springs) and so he eliminated the acceleration and displacement term from

$$\ddot{x} + 2\gamma \dot{x} + \omega^2x = f \cos(\omega t) \tag{1}$$

using

$$ \ddot{x}+\omega^2 x = 0 \tag{2}$$

Why can this be done? Would the $m\ddot{x}$ not be different due to the added driving force?

$$m\ddot{x} = -kx \tag{3}$$

So wouldn't
$$ \ddot{x}+\omega ^{2}x=0 \tag{4}$$
not be true?

Comment: Its not the mathematics that troubles me. Its the reason as to why you can still say the first equation holds true even though there is a whole other force (in this case $f=Fcos(\omega t)$

Comment: I think there are still errors in the equations.

Comment: I added equation numbers to make this easier. I follow the question through equation (2), but then I get lost. I'm not quite sure what you're asking starting with *"Would the $m\ddot{x}$ not be different..."* Why don't you come to the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) so we can talk in real time?

Comment: Why don't you ask your lecturer why he did this? He might appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can this be done?

It can be done because the driving function is at the (undamped) resonance frequency $\omega$.  To make it more clear, allow me first to rewrite (1) as

$$\ddot{x} + 2\gamma\dot{x} + \omega_0^2 x = f\cos(\omega t)$$

so that the undamped resonance frequency is $\omega_0$ and the driving frequency is $\omega$.  Now, assume the (steady state) solution is of the form $x(t) = A\cos(\omega t + \phi)$ and then

$$\ddot{x} = -\omega^2 A\cos(\omega t + \phi) = -\omega^2 x$$

and see that when $\omega = \omega_0$, the following *is* true:

$$\ddot{x} + \omega_0^2 x = 0$$